# Why does 00000000 ^ 01000010 = 01000010? Shouldn't it be 0?

Tags: math, binary

Staff for my class provided this hash function that takes 0 and raises it to the value of an ascii character, and in her answer it says the answer (for ascii 'B') is 01000010 or 66. In my mind we are multiplying 0 by 0, 66 times. Why would that equal 66?

Here's the code:

```
int hash_it(char* needs_hashing)
{
unsigned int hash = 0;
for (int i=0, n=strlen(needs_hashing); i<n; i++)
    hash = (hash << 2) ^ needs_hashing[i];
return hash % HASHTABLE_SIZE;
}
```

She then goes on to explain it:

```
i = 0
hash = 0x00
needs_hashing[0] = 'B'  
hash << 2 =  0000
hash = 0x00 ^ 0x42  (0000 ^ 0100 0010) // <- 0 raised to 66
hash = 0x42  (0100 0010) //<-equals 66
```

Any help would be great, I am feeling really stupid.

Comment: Congratulations, you're the 20 millionth beginner to be confused by this! Don't feel bad, now you're an expert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `^` operation is not power or exponentiation or repeated multiplication, it is [exclusive or](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) (sometimes written XOR). That's how many computer languages such as C, C++, Java, and Python use the `^` character. Look that up in your notes--I'm sure your class has already covered it. Under that interpretation, the equation you give is correct.

Comment: AH yes okay I remember reading that now. Thank you so much.! I'll mark it as the answer as soon as it lets me.